# What is the most efficient way of building a 10 page php form with over 100 inputs?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

I am currently building a rather large php form with that will span across 10 pages and have well over 100 inputs. Each input will be stored in the DB. I was just wondering if there is an easier/more efficient way to do this. I am not even done with the first page and I'm already having trouble keeping track of the variables. I appreciate any tips or comments. Thanks!

What I am currently doing. Imagine doing this x 10 -

Form Example

```
<form action="/db" method="post">

<div class="field-container">
    <label for="name" class="default-label">Company Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="billing_company_name" id="name" size="50">
    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="<?php echo $current_user->user_login . "\n";?>">
</div>

<div class="field-container">
    <label for="name" class="default-label">Contact Person:</label>
    <input type="text" name="billing_contact_person" id="name" size="50">
</div>

<div class="field-container">
    <label for="name" class="default-label">Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="billing_address" id="name" size="50">
</div>

<div class="field-container">
    <label for="name" class="default-label">City:</label>
    <input type="text" name="billing_city" id="name" size="50">
</div>

<div class="field-container">
    <label for="name" class="default-label">State:</label>
    <input type="text" name="billing_state" id="name" size="5">
</div>

<div class="field-container">
    <label for="name" class="default-label">ZIP:</label>
    <input type="text" name="billing_zip" id="name" size="8">
</div>

<div class="field-container">
    <label for="name" class="default-label">Phone:</label>
    <input type="text" name="billing_phone" id="name" size="50">
</div>

<div class="field-container">
    <label for="name" class="default-label">Email Address:</label>
    <input type="text" name="billing_email" id="name" size="50">
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Go To Step 2">
</form>
```

Saving Data

```
// Insert data into mysql
$sql="INSERT INTO Forms (Form_date, username, billing_company_name,  
billing_contact_person, billing_address, billing_city, billing_state, billing_zip,  
billing_phone, billing_email)

VALUES (NOW(),'$username', '$billing_company_name', '$billing_contact_person',   
'$billing_address', '$billing_city', '$billing_state', '$billing_zip', 
'$billing_phone', 
'$billing_email' )";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of template engines, but ofcourse you can make it with pure PHP.
I suggest you to insert all needed values in a single table i.e. tb1
Then use this one

X.php

```
  include '../../smarty/libs/Smarty.class.php';
  Class X extends Smarty {
  public function assignArray($query, $result_name='') {

  $data = mysql_query($query);

  $results = array();
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data))
  $results[] = $row;

  if ($result_name != '') {
    $this->assign($result_name, $results);
    $this->assign($result_name.'_count', count($results));
  } else
  return $results;

}  
}

$x = new X();
$query = "SELECT name, size, label, flag, value, hidden
        FROM tb1 
        WHERE flag = 1";

    /*
    name                    |   size    |   label           |   flag    |   value   |   hidden      |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    billing_company_name    |   50      |   Company Name    |   1       |   login   |   username    |
    billing_contact_person  |   50      |   Contact Person  |   0       |   NULL    |   NULL        |
    billing_state           |   5       |   State           |   0       |   NULL    |   NULL        |
    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */



$x->assignArray($query, 'result');

 //not neccessary to select flag, value, hidden

 $query1 = "SELECT name, size, label, flag, value, hidden 
        FROM tb1 
        WHERE flag = 0";
 $x->assignArray($query1, 'result1');
 $x->smarty->display('billings.tpl');
```

billings.tpl:

```
<form action="/db" method="post">

{section name=i loop=$result1}
<div class="field-container">
<label for="name" class="default-label">{$result1[i].label}</label>
<input type="text" name="{$result1[i].name}" id="name" size="{$result1[i].size}">
<input type="hidden" name="{$result1[i].hidden}" value="{$result1[i].value}">
</div>
{/section}

{section name=i loop=$result}
<div class="field-container">
<label for="name" class="default-label">{$result[i].label}</label>
<input type="text" name="{$result[i].name}" id="name" size="{$result[i].size}">
</div>
{/section}

<input type="submit" value="Go To Step 2">
</form>
```

Of course if value="" field cannot be read from a database you can still iterate through your currentUser method in order to have dynamic values

Comment: With or without templating engines, +1 for DRYness. It seems much easier to add/edit a form by having each question/input as a row in a database of Questions, then hand-coding all that and the extremely high change of a typo screwing something up in a very quiet manner.

Answer (score 0):

If I were in your shoes I would use a configuration array (I will store in it labels, field names, input types, Db column names ... etc). then I will use that array to generate both the form and the insert queries.

(It may be simpler to do this with a framework like Zend or Symfony but I guess you are not planning to use a framework just for a form)

Answer (score 0):

You could save the form values into a text field in the database and json_encode the array of key=>values that way you only have 1 database column of data and it can grow to accommodate more or less fields (json_decode to get the data back out). However doing it this way you can't really use standard filters and sorting techniques from mysql directly on a particular column. You can also do both, have a separate column for the fields you know you need to search or sort on using mysql and the rest into a json_encoded text column. That can simplify the database. As for the code and form, do what was suggested by setting up a configuration array and building the form out from that (this will require you to write a script to convert the config array into the appropriate html/php code) or find a class out their that can do that already.